# JSP directory structure

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I've been starting doing some Java and JSP and now, I'm stuck. I'm not happy with having all static HTML's in the root-folder. If I would pack those into a separate folder. At the moment, I see two options: configure it in the web.xml, but that only works for the servlets afaik. Configuring Tomcat on the other hand might be an option, but it would break the internal logic, even if it worked.

Is there a correct way for organizing the files and not having that reflected in the URL?

Comment: Where do you want to see the static files instead? You can create sub-folders... All content inside a WAR will be served relative to its context path. If you're not happy with that you need rewrite rules on your web server (or tomcat). The correct way *is* to serve static files relative to the context path of the WAR as they belong to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you speak about static pages something like say header and footer.

You can place them under any subfolder say inside jsp/static/(subcontent) or depending on the type of your file you can group them even further.

Now the usage, since because you are with plain jsp and servlet the only option that I think makes sense for static content is that include them whereever required with include directive like:

```
 <%@include file="/pages/static/abc.html" %>
```

or forward the request to them with

```
<jsp:forward page="/pages/static/staticdata.html" />
```

Understanding that this is a pain, if the navigation needs to be changed you will have to change your code, then more advanced web framework like Struts, JSF, e.t.c makes sense, as navigation rules can be changed very easily without changing code (unless the flow causes model to change or any different scenario).

Along with navigation rules these framework also specify page building configuration like tiles in Struts, templates in JSF e.t.c

Comment: Hi! I thought about Spring, but as that's my first project, I'd like to get a grip without first. So, what you are saying is: if i have a page somePage.html in a folder /staticPages/, the URL would have to change to mainUrl/staticPages/somePage.html. No way to configure that to read mainUrl/somePage.html?

Comment: when you do include using include directive the content of page being included is added to the caller page, no change in url, when you do forward again no change in url, user wont see any change in url, its just that someone else is doing the work

Comment: so, what you are suggesting is, having no static pages whatsoever and doing everything with jsp's?

Comment: No, its just that in my answer page name is jsp the code will work fine if you have just plain html

Comment: ah, if I get it, it's a workaround of declaring files as JSP (although being static html), so they can be configured in the web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually map jsp files to urls in web.xml using

```
<jsp-file></jsp-file> tag
```

Example

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>somName</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>newFolder/mypage.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>somName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/oldUrl.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Hi! I know, but those got into the packages under the class-folder anyway. I'd like to know, how to organize the statics, mainly the html-files 8)